# All Images in the batch are same while training GAN

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

```
def train(self,gray_scale_image_dataset,color_image_dataset,test_image):
    SEED= 50
    random.seed(SEED)
    generator = self.generator_model()
    discriminator = self.discriminator_model()

    gray_scale_images = gray_scale_image_dataset
    colored_images = color_image_dataset

    gen_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate,beta1=0.5)
    dis_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate,beta1=0.5)
    for eachEpoch in range(self.epochs):

        with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
            for i in range(20):
                random.shuffle(gray_scale_image_dataset)
                random.shuffle(color_image_dataset)
            gray_scale_dataset_image = gray_scale_images[:self.batch_size]
            print(gray_scale_dataset_image.shape)
            color_dataset_image_batch = colored_images[:self.batch_size]
            #lets see which images are being trained

            self.draw_train_images(color_dataset_image_batch) 
            generated_image = generator(gray_scale_dataset_image)
            real_output = discriminator(color_dataset_image_batch)

            fake_output = discriminator(generated_image)
            print("What  Discriminator Thought about real_output = {} and fake output = {}".format(real_output[0],fake_output[0]))
            gen_loss = self.generator_loss(fake_output,generated_image,color_dataset_image_batch)
            dis_loss = self.discriminator_loss(fake_output,real_output)
            print("GEN LOSS {} and DISC = {}".format(gen_loss[0],dis_loss[0]))

        gen_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss,generator.trainable_variables)
        disc_gradients = disc_tape.gradient(dis_loss,discriminator.trainable_variables)
        gen_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gen_gradients, generator.trainable_variables))
        dis_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(disc_gradients, discriminator.trainable_variables))

        print ("EPOCHS COMPLETED = {} ".format(eachEpoch))
        self.draw_images(generator,test_image)
```

This is my train  function that actually trains the gan network. The generator and discriminator are two different networks and have been made following the paper, so there is no problem with that. My problem is with the images I am passing. I have checked the images, both `gray_scale_image_dataset,color_image_dataset` and they work well. But when I go to the `self.draw_train_images` function and try to draw them in matplotlib, only the first image is shown in the grid. The whole grid is filled with the first image and only this image is used in training the data, so I am getting a lot of error. Any help regarding this issue? Where am I messing things up?

Comment: Hi, you might want to take a look at my post for similar question, maybe that will help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65122089/6398487